# How can i select many List Items while holding down Shift-key in List View

Tags: list-view

I want to all List Items to selected in between two Items that i clicked while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>-key in a List View. Is there a plug-in for this? Or script that can be added to the master page or List View Webpart?

[image: Graphical description of what I ask for]

Comment: You could change to Datasheet View, then its possible to use the Shift-method. I do not know how its done in the Standard View.